# Writing predictions back to dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I am working on a few classification models in Jupyter notebook. I have now experimented with a number of different algorithms and have determined which one is the optimal choice.

I need to write the predictions back to the original dataframe (train/test data)? Is there any instructions to show how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using sklearn.

```
# model is the trained model. df is the features you are using for prediction
y = model.predict(df)
# just create a new column in the dataframe you predicted and assign it to the prediction
df['prediction'] = y
```